JavaScript - доступ к объекту, ссылка на который не была сохранена в переменной
Столкнулся с участком кода, где объект создается, но ссылка на него не записывается в переменную, примерно такого вида
    NameSpace.ObjectConstructor.create(params);

Методе create возвращает объект, созданный через конструкцию
    var self = new NameSpace.ObjectConstructor(params);
    return self;

Ссылка на объект, возвращаемая методом create никуда не записывается.
Переменную self объявленную через var в объекте windows найти не смог.
Подскажите, можно ни найти объект созданный таким образом, не меняя указанный код? То есть без добавления события в метод create и без конструкции  let obj = NameSpace.ObjectConstructor.create(params). То есть найти его отдельным кодом.

Область видимости переменной, объявленной через var, ограничивается, в твоем случае, методом, в котором было объявление. Т.ч. ответ на твой вопрос можно ни найти объект созданный таким образом, не меняя указанный код? - нет.

Понял, спасибо.
А вообще есть в JS возможность доступа к лексическому окружению, области видимости, куче объектов? Или это всё скрыто под капотом?

В общем смысле ответ отрицательный...

Если в JS что то порождено и не используется, а так же отсутствует ссылка на это порождение, то оно удаляется сборщиком мусора. Так что если вам что то надо что то создать, а потом к нему обратиться, то надо сохранять в какую нибудь переменную

Понял, спасибо.
До меня код дошел уже в таком виде.
Объект, не смотря на такой алгоритм создания, работает, не удаляется.
Искал пути кастомизировать его, не переписывая код компонента.
Спасибо за ответы.
